# Get single key value from JSON with Node

Tags: node.js, json, api

I'm using a `RESTFUL API` to get some `JSON` data, this is the code:

```
const request= require('request');

const options = { 
    url: 'https://myurl.com/',
    headers: {
        'x-functions-key': 'mykey'
    }
};

request.get(options, (err, response, body) =>{
    if(err){
        console.log("Error!")
    }

    const obj = JSON.parse(body);

    //console.log(obj.id);
    console.log(body);

});
```

This is the `response` from `console.log` if I only use the `body` parameter:

```
{
    "id": "19678u36-au71-4112-0057-950jjkca61d1",
    "phone": "",
    "address": "{\"cep\":\"00000-000\",\"city\":\"Belo Horizonte\",\"state\":\"MG\",\"country\":\"Brasil\",\"street\":\"My Street\",\"district\":\"My District\",\"number\":\"000\",\"complement\":\"000\"}",
    "items": "{\"tax\":12,\"amount\":2,\"items\":[{\"type\":\"NILO\",\"name\":\"Nilo Zack\",\"quantity\":1}]}",
    "userEmail": "marcel@onboardmobility.com",
    "userData": "{\"name\":\"User Name\",\"document\":\"000.000.000-00\",\"phone\":\"\",\"email\":\"user@email.com\"}",
    "order": "{\"tid\":\"ch_5PXxuyoqw4\",\"notes\":\"XQ22ARP\",\"status\":2}",
    "createdAt": "2020-05-05T17:50:45.707Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-05T17:50:45.708Z"
  },
```

I want to print only the `id` key, but when I run the `console.log(obj.id)` I get an `undefined` response from the console. Any ideas? Maybe I'm not parsing correctly the `JSON` data, dunno. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the fact that there is a `,` in your `body`, I assume that response is not an object, but an array.

```
request.get(options, (err, response, body) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Error!")
    }

    const items = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(items[0].id);
});
```

Comment: Yeah! Sorry about the noob question, I'm new to this. What if I have an array inside of this array? Like this:  { "address": "{\"cep\":\"30410-600\",\"city\":\"Belo Horizonte\"}"},? I need to use the position on the "adress" too, isn't?

Comment: If your data is inside curly braces - it is an object. If your data is inside square brackets - it is an array. You don't need to use the index on the "address" because it has an object - use `address.city` e.g.

Comment: In case it answers your question, please mark it as answered. There is a checkbox to the left from the answer. Thanks!